# Function specialization in generic class c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class called `PointValue`, `PointValue` and his inheritors can be created only by parametrized constructor that receives one float parameter.

I have a generic class that represents a list of points, template type must inherit from `PointValue`.

I need that one of the functions would have the ability to add points to the list, because I can't enforce using templates a parametrized constructor. my function gets a `pointValueCreator` to create the new point.

```
public class PointList<PointValueT> where PointValueT : PointValue
{
  public void addPointToList(float f, Func<float,PointValueT> pointValueCreator)
  {
     // do something to f and then add a new point: 
     mylist.Add(pointValueCreator(f));
  }
}
```

So now if I have something like this:

```
PointList<PointValue> bla = new PointList<PointValue>();
```

I can call my function like this:

```
bla.addPointToList(f, (myfloat) => new PointValue(myfloat));
```

My question is how can I create specialization for `addPointToList` for my `PointValue` inheritors, to avoid passing creators.

something like:

```
public void addPointToList(float f)
{
this.addPointToList(f, (myfloat) => new PointValue(myfloat));
}
```

I've tried to do it, but the compiler says: 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'PointValue' to 'PointValueT'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I understand that c# doesn't have specialization, if that is the case, maybe some "design" trick can help me ?
Let's say I have PointValueA and PointValueB inherting, how can i avoid passing creators for each one of them manually ?

Comment: remove `<PointValue>`.

Comment: In c# they are known as _generics_ **not** templates.

Comment: Hi @Amit, I've edited the question, i wrote it accidentally. still the question is the same.

Comment: Not confident enough to answer but.... I'm going to say you cannot. The creator pattern you're currently using is the way to go.

Comment: What's the purpose here? how do you want to create an object of an unknown type, with an unknown constructor? or do you only want to allow creation of the base type (`PointValue`), and if so, why no add a protected `addPointToList` for that?

Comment: my purpose is to create 2-3 specialization for classes I use a lot to avoid passing creators every time I call "addPointToList". I'm pretty sure that in C++ I've did exactly that. It is very convinient

Comment: Why do you want to avoid passing the factory?

Comment: How about making the factory function an abstract of the base type (or non-abstract, but virtual), and overriding it in subclasses, so that you don't have to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @Amit,I thought about it, but what would be the return type of the factory function ?  each inheritor should have a different return type

Comment: Why? just return `PointValue`, it's a shared base class.

Comment: The list is generic, it expects PointValueT, I can't add PointValue, I need to up cast it.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought that the most basic way to handle this is by passing the factory through the constructor, rather than for each call to `addPointToList`.

```
public class PointList<PointValueT> where PointValueT : PointValue
{
    public PointList(Func<float, PointValueT> pointValueCreator)
    {
        this.pointValueCreator = pointValueCreator;
    }
    Func<float, PointValueT> pointValueCreator;
    private List<PointValueT> mylist = new List<PointValueT>();
    public void addPointToList(float f)
    {
        mylist.Add(pointValueCreator(f));
    }
}
```

This would then be called like this:

```
PointList<PointValue> bla = new PointList<PointValue>((myfloat) => new PointValue(myfloat));

bla.addPointToList(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specialise generic in C# like you can with templates in C++.

It would be nice to be able to specify constructor arguments in constraints (i.e. `where PointValueT : PointValue, new(float)` ), but the language doesn't allow that.

There are a couple of solutions to achieve what you want:

1: use a creator pattern like you're already doing

2: instead of setting the float in the constructor, set it as a property.

```
public class PointValue
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

public class PointList<PointValueT> 
    where PointValueT : PointValue, new()
{
  public void addPointToList(float f)
  {
     // do something to f and then add a new point: 
     mylist.Add(new PointValueT { Value = f });
  }
}
```

This does mean you can't make your PointValue immutable though.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of specialize using inheritance

```
public class PointValueList : PointList<PointValue>
{
    public void addPointToList(float f)
    {
        addPointToList(f, (myfloat) => new PointValue(myfloat));
    }
}
```

and then on that new inherited or specialized class you can just call

```
bla.addPointToList(f);
```

Also depending on your needs you can make the base class abstract and declare

```
public abstract void addPointToList(float f);
```

in the base class and then override in derived specialization classes

But yes, as Enigmativity suggested, passing factory through the constructor makes more sense at least with this simple example.